# docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on Mac OS X

Tags: docker

I got the following error when I run docker. Does anybody know how to fix the problem. The OS is Mac OS X.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
$ docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: Docker doesn't have to be running for `docker --version` to return a result. You'll need to start docker! To clarify - `docker run` is trying to run a container, you need to actually start the daemon. If you're using the native app you can do this by opening the Docker app

Comment: I got this `$ docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: Bad response from Docker engine.
` when I run `/Applications/Docker.app`.

Comment: Try to run **Diagnose and Feedback...**.

Comment: I just realize that I need to run `docker pull hello-world` first. Thanks.

Comment: Funnily enough I just had to actually run the Docker app that was installed

Answer (score 4):

**You can restart Docker with the following**

**Stop Docker for Mac gracefully**

**Stop all Docker containers without confirmation (make sure nothing is running in Docker)**

```
docker ps -q | xargs -L1 docker stop
```

**Requires all Docker containers are stopped**

```
test -z "$(docker ps -q 2>/dev/null)" && osascript -e 'quit app "Docker"'
```

**Start Docker gracefully**

```
open --background -a Docker
```

Comment: thanks this worked , what does this command really do ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer with the least effort but it helped to solve my problem which I was debugging for a couple of hours: **Reboot your macOS.**

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I have to restart my docker desktop as well. I had no idea that docker desktop and terminal's docker command are related. But now, apparently, they are related. If anyone encounters similar problems, remember to try restart your docker desktop and wait for it to get running!